# Separate dev, staging, production environment in AWS ECS with ECS, without creating separate cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

How can I separate dev, staging, production environment in ECS(with EC2), so that I can test with dev and staging environment, and deploy to production environment, etc, using the same set of containers.

The problem is, if I want to use the same EC2 instance for dev and staging environment, I can't create separate ECS cluster since every EC2 instance belongs to one cluster.